# Chiral fermions from torsion flux in M-theory?

Tags: string-theory, research-level, standard-model, fermions, chirality

Witten's 1981 paper ["Search for a realistic Kaluza-Klein theory"](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0550321381900213) is frequently cited for its observation that, in a compactification of d=11 supergravity on a manifold with SU(3) x SU(2) x U(1) isometry, left-handed and right-handed fermions would transform in the same way under the gauge group, in opposition to experiment. Years later, in the era of M-theory, [Acharya and Witten](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0109152) were able to get chiral fermions by compactifying on a manifold with singularities. But Witten 1981 also mentioned, at the end, that coupling to a torsion field might produce chiral asymmetry. (Subsequent explorations of the idea: [for](http://prd.aps.org/abstract/PRD/v33/i2/p363_1) and [against](http://jmp.aip.org/resource/1/jmapaq/v25/i9/p2696_s1).)

Now I'm wondering: **Can torsion in M-theory revive the 1970s version of Kaluza-Klein theory?** A [very recent paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.2299) constructed CFT duals for M-theory on AdS<sub>4</sub> x M<sup>111</sup> with torsion flux, M<sup>111</sup> being one of the "M<sup>pqr</sup> manifolds" with SU(3) x SU(2) x U(1) isometry group that was considered in Witten 1981. (The M<sup>pqr</sup> notation is Witten's; in a more recent notation this manifold is designated M<sup>3,2</sup> or sometimes Y<sup>2,3</sup>.) Can M-theory on such a background give rise to chiral fermions?

Comment: Good links. I am afraid that you found expert enough papers that you would have to ask their authors to stage a battle here instead of asking someone else. ;-) Did Wu and Zee really say that they can't get chirality? It looks that they only say that they don't get the right representations.

Comment: "We conclude that with the introduction of torsion, Kaluza-Klein theories can have massless fermions, but not chiral fermions."